# SparkException: Task not serializable caused by scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11

Tags: apache-spark

I was trying to run a tutorial program (JavaPipelineExample.java) from Spark examples that classifies text documents. [JavaPipelineExample.java](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaPipelineExample.java)

But is giving me an error in the list, when I am trying to fit the pipeline to the training documents.

```
        Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
                .setStages(new PipelineStage[]{tokenizer, hashingTF, lr});

        // Fit the pipeline to training documents.
        PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(training);
```

The error is

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11
```

I am really puzzled by this error as all my classes are serializable. Can someone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: A query on `SparkException "Task not serializable"` returns 11 hits in StackOverflow alone. Why don't you read these posts???

Comment: Also, remember that Spark is written in Scala. There has to be some impedance mismatch when using the Java API.

Comment: @Samsom, I did read all of them but they were all caused by different issues. I am yet to find someone who has got the same error like me in Java.